# Cannot use custom element in React and Angular

Tags: reactjs, angular, angularjs

I created a custom element in React using `reactToWebComponent`.  In a simple HTML file, I use it as follows

```
<body>
    <custom-tag></custom-tag>
    <script src="http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

Everything is working fine and it displays the component from `<custom-tag>`.

However, when I use it in another React app, I got an error saying

```
Property 'custom-tag' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.
```

So I resort to doing the following and it works

```
React.createElement('custom-tag', {...props})
```

When I use it in an Angular app, I got an error saying

```
'custom-tag' is not a known element
```

How to properly use a custom element in Angular?  For React, is there another way that I don't need to use `React.createElement` instead use the tag `<custom-tag>` directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching, I was able to do it as follows:

For react, we need to add this code inside `react-app-env.d.ts`

```
declare namespace JSX {
    interface IntrinsicElements {
        "custom-tag": {
            prop1: string;
            prop2: string;
            ...
        };
    }
}
```

For angular, we need to update `app.module.ts` and add the custom element schema:

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core'
@NgModule({
    ...
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
    ...
})
```

Then for both react and angular app, we can simply use it as `<custom-tag prop1="val1" ...></custom-tag>`